# Iterating over a list with 8526 items in it, getting index out of range error

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

Python newbie here. I have been working on a small script which converts XML to CSV for a project at work. There are 406 elements in the XML data which has been parsed into memory, and each element has 21 indexfields that are children to that element, making a total of 8,526 indexfields.

Of those 21 index fields for a given element, I would like to pull the 0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 6th, 7th, and 8th items.

I've created a loop (similar to the code below) to do the following:

```
i = 0
files = 406
docrange = 8526
iterstep = 21
pad = '","'
for docs in range(i, docrange):
    string1 = str('"'+indexfields[iterstep])+pad)
    string2 = str(indexfields[iterstep+1])+pad)
    string3 = str(indexfields[iterstep+2])+pad)
    string5 = str(indexfields[iterstep+3])+pad)
    string6 = str(indexfields[iterstep+5])+pad)
    string7 = str(indexfields[iterstep+6])+pad)
    string8 = str(indexfields[iterstep+7])+pad)
    string9 = str(indexfields[iterstep+8])+pad)
    strung = string1+string2+string3+string5+string6+string7+string8+string9
    print strung

    iterstep = (iterstep + 21)
    i = (i + 1)
```

When I enter this loop I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "Path/To/My/script.py", line 55, in <module> 
string1 = (str(indexfields[iterstep])) IndexError: list index out of range
```

From what I gather, I do not think I am modifying the list that I am iterating over, as other threads on Stack Overflow dealing with this error seems to indicate.

While I know that there is way more elegant ways to write the code above, I would like to get the XML data converted into CSV quickly, and need to get this job wrapped up.

Edit1: This may not be the appropriate place for it, but here is an example of the Files.xml the index information is being pulled from. There is another XML file that is being used in conjunction with Files.xml, I can post that as well if needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<File>
  <ExtendedProperties />
  <ID>7514</ID>
  <SyncFlag>Edit</SyncFlag>
  <CustomSort />
  <ViewerContext>None</ViewerContext>
  <ProjectID>1</ProjectID>
  <BoxID>0</BoxID>
  <FileID>7514</FileID>
  <FilePtr>0</FilePtr>
  <Status>Active</Status>
  <KeyValue />
  <KeyVisualValue />
  <Field>
    <string>Some words that I would like to pull1</string>
    <string>Some words that I would like to pull2</string>
    <string>Some words that I would like to pull3</string>
    <string>Some words that I would like to pull4</string>
    <string>Nonsense</string>
    <string>Some words that I would like to pull5</string>
    <string>Some words that I would like to pull6</string>
    <string>Some words that I would like to pull7</string>
    <string>Some words that I would like to pull8</string>
    <string>Some words that I would like to pull9</string>
    <string>Nonsense</string>
    <string>Nonsense</string>
    <string />
    <string />
    <string />
    <string />
    <string />
    <string />
    <string />
    <string />
    <string />
  </Field>
  <Notes />
  <DateStarted>2015-07-16T11:02:00</DateStarted>
  <DateChanged>2015-12-09T14:46:58.7335221-05:00</DateChanged>
  <ChangedBy>1</ChangedBy>
  <Destruction>1990-01-01T01:00:00</Destruction>
  <LabelPrinted>1990-01-01T01:00:00</LabelPrinted>
  <SaveStyle>NewFile</SaveStyle>
  <SaveNotesOnly>false</SaveNotesOnly>
  <FileVerifyLevels>0</FileVerifyLevels>
  <RemoteID>1</RemoteID>
</File>
```

Here is a snippit from the Documents.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Document>
  <ID>262601</ID>
  <SyncFlag>Edit</SyncFlag>
  <CustomSort />
  <ViewerContext>None</ViewerContext>
  <FileID>1647</FileID>
  <RelProjectID>0</RelProjectID>
  <ArchiveID>0</ArchiveID>
  <Archive />
  <DocumentID>262601</DocumentID>
  <Status>Active</Status>
  <Separator>Some words to pull</Separator>
  <Divider>Some words to pull</Divider>
</Document>
```

Edit2:
Some great responses came about from you all, I found that the cause of my original error was due to an iteration value being set initially to 21 instead of 0.
I need a little more guidance with this software, would it be better to open a new thread?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback error message with line numbers, it will help indicate which line is causing the error.

Comment: Side note: you can accomplish the same thing as all of your string statements with: `string = '"' + '","'.join([str(indexfields[iterstep + i]) for i in range(9)])`

Comment: Brendan,

Here is the traceback:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Path/To/My/script.py", line 55, in <module>
    string1 = (str(indexfields[iterstep]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That says the problem is in the indexing of `indexfields`, which you haven't shown us.  (Also, the code in the traceback doesn't match the code you posted...)

Comment: is iterstep the same as istep? Also why are you doing `i = (i + 1)`?

Comment: What is the initial value of `indexfields` ?

Comment: Yes, iterstep and istep should have been the same thing; editing original question now to reflect that.

Comment: indexfields is a list which contains every 'string' in 'Field'

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:  Your main focus here should be learning how to read the stack trace.  What this is telling you is that after a certain loop, you are trying to access an index that is not yet populated.  Try printing the indexes as you go and see what happens.

For future work on this I would suggest using XML Parsing to go through this instead.

You should be handling this conversion dynamically as opposed to always assuming there will be x elements.

Python has built in modules to parse XML and use Xpath. https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

This gives you the ability to parse individual nodes, access attributes etc.

Comment: Although this is a totally valid (and arguably the best) solution for general xml parsing, I would encourage the original poster to work on learning the basics of Python (avoiding needless repetition, debugging off by x errors) before trying to get Python's xml libraries to work.

Comment: I agree.  I myself found working with the libraries just as easy.  But that's me. I updated my answer with debugging support.

Comment: Sure -- it is probably easier, but understanding these basic concepts will help him debug library issues which can easily get far more complicated than this particular iteration error. And I don't have any issue with your answer. I just want OP also to understand the issue with this particular script.

Comment: Thank Alex! I do too.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is that you say you have 406 rows and 21 elements in each row totaling 8562 elements. This means you need to loop over the number of rows. If you increase iterstep by 21, 8562 times, then iterstep will equal 179802 which is 21 times the number of elements you have. So you need to change your range to `range(i,files)`. You are also starting your iterstep from `21` when you probably need to be starting it from zero

```
files = 406
docrange = 8526
iterstep = 0
pad = '","'
for i in range(0, files):
    string1 = str('"'+indexfields[iterstep])+pad)
    string2 = str(indexfields[iterstep+1])+pad)
    string3 = str(indexfields[iterstep+2])+pad)
    string5 = str(indexfields[iterstep+3])+pad)
    string6 = str(indexfields[iterstep+5])+pad)
    string7 = str(indexfields[iterstep+6])+pad)
    string8 = str(indexfields[iterstep+7])+pad)
    string9 = str(indexfields[iterstep+8])+pad)
    strung = string1+string2+string3+string5+string6+string7+string8+string9
    print strung

    iterstep += 21
```

or a better way of doing this is to remove iterstep and just use xranges step parameter and step 21 each time

```
files = 406
docrange = 8526
pad = '","'
for i in range(0, docrange, 21):
    string1 = str('"'+indexfields[i])+pad)
    string2 = str(indexfields[i+1])+pad)
    string3 = str(indexfields[i+2])+pad)
    string5 = str(indexfields[i+3])+pad)
    string6 = str(indexfields[i+5])+pad)
    string7 = str(indexfields[i+6])+pad)
    string8 = str(indexfields[i+7])+pad)
    string9 = str(indexfields[i+8])+pad)
    strung = string1+string2+string3+string5+string6+string7+string8+string9
    print strung
```

Comment: Why the downvote? 21 * 8562 = 179802 which is way more elements than OP has

Comment: That's a good point.
The final output needs to have as many lines as there are docs, 8526. For every set of files out there, we must pull the relevant index strings from the Files.xml.
So there will be 406 sets of unique index info strings pulled and printed on 8526 lines, which point to 8526 unique documents.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is certainly caused by `iterstep`, you are starting it from 21 and incrementing it by 21 on every iteration. Perhaps you should keep it at 0 and you have to do something with the `i` (because changing it in the loop doesn't affect the `range`) or remove it completely.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have read all your data into a single, LARGE, flat array called `indexfields`.

If so, this was probably a bad call on your part - you threw away some information.

Regardless, you now need to step through the indexfields in groups of 21 items. This is fairly easy to do:

```
for i in range(0, len(indexfields), 21):
```

At this point, you have `i` equal to some number that is a multiple of 21. You'll extract the subset of fields you care about using the index offsets you have already determined:

```
    offsets = (0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8)
    fields = [indexfields[i+j] for j in offsets]
```

At this point, you can print the values or feed them into one of the many, many, many libraries that exist for CSV file manipulation. Here's a simple print-to-stdout version:

```
    q = '"'
    q_q = '","'
    csv_line = q + q_q.join(fields) + q
    print(csv_line)
```

Cleaning it up:

```
# Fake up some data
indexfields = []

fake="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
for i in range(0,406):
    for j in range(0,21):
        indexfields.append(str(i) + "-" + fake[j])

offsets = (0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8)
q = '"'
q_q = '","'

for i in range(0, len(indexfields), 21):
    fields = [indexfields[i+j] for j in offsets]

    csv_line = q + q_q.join(fields) + q
    print(csv_line)
```